# Is it possible to change the view size of iOS 8 Action Extension?

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm developing an action extension for iOS 8 at the moment. I want the view to be full screen, and it is on the iPhones, but not on the iPad, on the iPad my extension is presented in a small view in the middle. Is it possible to make it so that it's full screen on the iPad too?

[image: Action Extension view not taking up the full screen size on iPad]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of searching around I found all I needed to do was put

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(760.0f, 1024)];
```

in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 5):

According to Apple's [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1) you need to add a new boolean value for `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` in the `NSExtension` dictionary.

```xml
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```