# How to display an action extension in a form sheet?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am working on an action extension. By default, I can see that my extension is taking whole screen, I would like it to be presented in a form sheet (like the facebook share extension). How to accomplish that?

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is what I've found, but I need the other way around.
[Is it possible to change the view size of iOS 8 Action Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871916/is-it-possible-to-change-the-view-size-of-ios-8-action-extension)
Adding lines to `NSExtension` doesn't do much:

```
<key>NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation</key>
<false/>
```